# The import org.openqa.selenium.chrome cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

On Eclipse, The error red line was showing below the ChromeDriver statement and Line 18 (WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver).  Is that code correct?

Code:

```
package firsttestngpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FirstTestNGFile {
    public String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/";
    String driverPath= 
    "C:\\Users\\manoj\\Documents\\QA\\COURSE\\ChromeDriver94\\chromedriver.exe";
    //public WebDriver driver; 

@Test
public void f() {
   System.out.println("launching chrome browser"); 
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.get(baseUrl);
   String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
   String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
   Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
   driver.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you manage dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it looks fine to me.

Additionally, you'd have to import `WebDriver` as well.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
```

If that still did not work, I would suggest to take `WebDriver driver` out of `@Test`

**Sample code :**

```
private WebDriver driver;

public String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/";
String driverPath = "C:\\Users\\manoj\\Documents\\QA\\COURSE\\ChromeDriver94\\chromedriver.exe";

@Test
public void f() {
    System.out.println("launching chrome browser"); 
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
    String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
    driver.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 


// Few important imports in selenium to look.
// WebDriver interface is important for using methods
   get(),getCurrentUrl(),findElement(),close(),quit() etc
```